# Python read every json object and assign variable to each data line

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this json file:

```
{
    "id": "manager",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "user1",
            "children": [],
            "data": {
                "name": "john",
                "age": "55",
                "lastname": "smith",
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "user2",
            "children": [],
            "data": {
                "name": "mark",
                "age": "56",
                "lastname": "guri",
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "user3",
            "children": [],
            "data": {
                "name": "alex",
                "age": "57",
                "lastname": "muller",
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "name": "sukri",
        "age": "24",
        "lastname": "adam"
    }
}
```

I am trying to assign a variable to each of those information under children. so I can access them later on..

The challenge is to iterate through all children under manager.
Result should be like:
children1{id=user1, name=john, age="55"}
children2{...}
children3{...}

And it should go to the end of the list and capture all info.

Please let me know how to achieve this. I have the following code which doesn't work:

```
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print ("id:", data['manager'])
    print ("")
    for children in data['manager']:
        print("name:", children['name'])
        print("age:", children['age'])
        print("lastname:", children['lastname'])
        print("")
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you trying to do exactly? Are you just trying to print out all the information or do you need to store it?

Comment: When I run the script, the output is "None" - All I want is the data inside children. For example manager has 3 children with info. I need those info to assigne variable to,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list with the data for each of the children with something like this.

```py
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

children = [child['data'] for child in data['children']]

print(children)
```

```
[{'name': 'john', 'age': '55', 'lastname': 'smith'}, {'name': 'mark', 'age': '56', 'lastname': 'guri'}, {'name': 'alex', 'age': '57', 'lastname': 'muller'}]
```

Alternatively, you could create a dictionary of the children with this.

```py
children_dict = {f'user{id+1}': child['data'] for id, child in enumerate(data['children'])}

print(children_dict['user1'])
```

```
{'name': 'john', 'age': '55', 'lastname': 'smith'}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Is it also possible to categorize them by id? like user1 = [{data}]

Comment: Not 100% sure what you  mean but I've added another option that creates a dictionary which will allow you to access the data by id.